# Correlation table with two methods in one table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, correlation

I like to create one correlation table which contains two correlation coefficents. (pearson and spearman)

I know that I can create with df.corr(method='spearman') a correlation table.

Do you know if it's possible that the same table contains the 'pearson' and 'spearman' coefficent? 
Like the pearson is underneath the spearman coefficent in brackets.

Thank you

For example:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you'd like to achieve? Is it a tuple like this: `(pearson_coeff, spearman_coeff)`, for each cell?

Comment: i added an example. But a tuple would be fine too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not pretty, but maybe something along these lines:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,3))                                                
c1 = df.corr()                                                                        
c2 = df.corr(method='spearman')                                                       
corr_df = c1.applymap(lambda x: [x]) + c2.applymap(lambda x: [x])
```

Output:

```
                            0                            1                            2
0                  [1.0, 1.0]    [0.5457412669991152, 0.5]   [-0.533894951027147, -0.5]
1   [0.5457412669991152, 0.5]                   [1.0, 1.0]  [-0.9999009746183144, -1.0]
2  [-0.533894951027147, -0.5]  [-0.9999009746183144, -1.0]                   [1.0, 1.0]
```